# Stripe Onboarding Flow: Stripe Onboarding Screens not coming up

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to onboard a customer for a Stripe Express account by using the Stripe API. I create an account requesting the relevant capabilities, providing simple information like first name, last name and email, and the account is created successfully. I expected the Stripe website to come up to request the missing information from the customer (like DOB, bank account info,...), but instead, the account creation just finishes and the account is restricted due to the missing information. Do I have to redirect the user after checking what the status of the account is? What's the flow?

This is the start_onboarding() method of my teacher_us object:

```
    // methods
    function start_onboarding() {
        // load Stripe library--- moved to the main plugin file
        // require_once('..\vendor\autoload.php');
        global $stripe_api_key;
        $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient($stripe_api_key);
        $stripe_account = $stripe->accounts->create([
            'type'          =>  'express',
            'country'       =>  'US',
            'business_type' =>  'individual',
            'email'         =>  $this->get_email(),
            'individual'    =>  [
                'first_name'    =>  $this->get_first_name(),
                'last_name'     =>  $this->get_last_name(),
            ],
            'capabilities'      => [
                'transfers'     =>  ['requested' => true],
                'card_payments' =>  ['requested' => true],
            ],
        ]);
```

It seems that just calling this method doesn't make Stripe to collect the missing info. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

This does not happen automatically. After creating the Express account, you must [create an Account Link](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts#create-link) for Connect Onboarding, and [redirect your user to the `url` it includes](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts#redirect-link) to go through the onboarding flow to provide the rest of the required information.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Nolan! Following the documentation you pointed me to did the job!